# .items() doesn't work in my created class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I wrote this script:

```
class MonDictionnaire:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionnaire = {}
    def __add__(self, objetàajouter):
        nouvelle_valeure = MonDictionnaire()
        nouvelle_valeure.dictionnaire = self.dictionnaire
        nouvelle_valeure.dictionnaire = dict(self.dictionnaire.items() + objetàajouter.items()
```

then I wanted two objects in this class like:

```
>>>>fruit = MonDictionnaire()
>>> fruit.dictionnaire["pommes"] = 13
>>> fruit.dictionnaire["poires"] = 12
>>> fruit.dictionnaire["pruneau"] = 11
>>> legume = MonDictionnaire()
>>> legume.dictionnaire["poireau"] = 10
>>> legume.dictionnaire["panet"] = 9
```

then I just wanted to add my two objects like:

```
>>> fruit = fruit + legume
```

but the shell return me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
fruit = fruit + legume
File "D:\Python\Dictionnaire.py", line 9, in __add__
nouvelle_valeure.dictionnaire = dict(self.dictionnaire.items() + objetàajouter.items())
AttributeError: 'MonDictionnaire' object has no attribute 'items'
```

and I don't get why as my created class is a dictionnary???!!! 
thank you so much for helping me!!!

Comment: You never defined an `items` method, why would you expect it to exist?

Comment: "I don't get why as my created class is a dictionnary" no it is not. It neither inherits from `dict` nor does it implement any of the necessary mapping methods, so in no sense is it a dictionary. It *contains* a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your issue is with this line:

```
nouvelle_valeure.dictionnaire = dict(self.dictionnaire.items() + objetàajouter.items()
```

When you call: `fruit = fruit + legume` your class is trying to call `.items()` on `legume`.  I think this change should work as you expect:

```
nouvelle_valeure.dictionnaire = dict(self.dictionnaire.items() + objetàajouter.dictionnaire.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the instance attribute:

```
self.dictionnaire = {}
```

whereas in `objetàajouter.items()` you're trying to get the `items` method of the instance itself, which is not present.

You need to explicitly specify the attribute:

```
objetàajouter.dictionnaire.items()
```

Also, were you meant to subclass `dict`?